# How can I count the number of stores for each address?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that finds rows with duplicate street names:

```
SELECT a.id, a.street1, a.postal_code, a.fk_countryID
FROM address a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b.street1, b.postal_code, b.fk_countryID
  FROM address b
  GROUP BY b.street1, b.postal_code
  HAVING count(b.id) > 1
) duplicate ON a.street1 = duplicate.street1 
AND a.postal_code = duplicate.postal_code
AND a.fk_countryID = duplicate.fk_countryID
ORDER BY a.street1, a.postal_code
```

The result is (ignore NumStores column):

```
+-------+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-----------+
| id    | street          | postalCode | city | CC  | NumStores |
+-------+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-----------+
| 11101 | Bogstadveien 36 | 0366       | Oslo | NO  |     ?     |
| 11102 | Bogstadveien 36 | 0366       | Oslo | NO  |     ?     |
| 11103 | Bogstadveien 36 | 0366       | Oslo | NO  |     ?     |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

The goal is to delete duplicate rows. In order to do this job, I need to see how many stores is actually using each address. The ones with 0 count I can delete right away. The ones with 1 or more I have to "move" to the address I want to use before deletion. This is all done manually through GUI (JS/PHP).

So the question is; How can I add the number of stores for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something that works.

```
SELECT a.id, a.street1, a.postal_code, a.fk_countryID, COUNT(c.fk_addressID) as NumStores
(...)
LEFT JOIN store c
ON a.id = c.fk_addressID
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.street1, a.postal_code;
```

The result is:

```
+-------+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-----------+
| id    | street          | postalCode | city | CC  | NumStores |
+-------+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-----------+
| 11101 | Bogstadveien 36 | 0366       | Oslo | NO  |     0     |
| 11102 | Bogstadveien 36 | 0366       | Oslo | NO  |     0     |
| 11103 | Bogstadveien 36 | 0366       | Oslo | NO  |     3     |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Glad you fixed this! I'm sorry I walked away from SO for a few days so I didn't get to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would write one subquery to get the count of stores per address using simple aggregation like this:

```
SELECT address, COUNT(*) AS numStores
FROM storeTable
GROUP BY address;
```

Looking at your question, there might be a join involved here as you don't keep address in the store table, so I've shortened it to just demonstrate how you would get that. Then, you join it into your other table like this:

```
SELECT stuff, tmp.numStores
FROM stuffTables
JOIN(
   SELECT address, COUNT(*) AS numStores
   FROM storeTable
   GROUP BY address) tmp ON tmp.address = stuffTables.address;
```

Comment: Yes, sub query is the way to go I think. But I'm not sure what you mean. The Store table contains the ID of the address `store.fk_addressID`. So I don't understand your join.

Comment: @Steven because as shown by your table the fk_addressID can appear more than once for each address, right? Do you want the number of stores for 'Bogstadveien 36' or do you want the number of stores for address '11101'

Comment: I want to the number of stores using the address with ID '11101'

Comment: @Steven then you don't need the join, you can just group by `fk_addressID` in my example. I will rewrite it in the morning I'm sorry.